# returning char** from C DLL to VB

Tags: c, vb.net, dll

Please, I am developing a VB app to call a C DLL function and I need to pass from VB to C DLL a char** to receive the reply. How can I do that? Thanks everybody!

Comment: I don't know VB, but does it support pointers? What do you think a `char **` actually is?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: The first result on Goolge: [How To Write C DLLs and Call Them from Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/106553).

Comment: @Olaf : VB/VB.NET doesn't support pointers. C# does however.

Comment: @VisualVincent: The question is about VB. So simple answer would be "you can't". Anyway, I'm out, not my world.

Comment: @Olaf : I know it's in VB, but my point was to answer your question and include an alternative that actually _does_ support pointers. Even though you/the OP don't use C# it is never wrong to be aware of little extra information. It might also help someone that actually is using the language :). -- Besides, even though C#'s and VB's syntax is different, they're still very much alike due to that they're .NET Framework languages. It would have been one thing if I said C++ which is completely different. -- Anyway, I'm not to start a discussion about this. Good luck in the future. :)

Comment: @I knew the other languages do (ok, a bit surprised about C#, but I'm not interested in that language anyway). Re "they are very much alike" due to using the same run-time interpreter - sorry, but that is nonsense. With the same you could state Cython, Brainfuck, APL/1, Ada and C are much the same as they all use the same CPU instruction set after compilation. Or C and C++ are the same because they even use the similar syntax (but not necessarily identical semantics even for the same constructs). Anyway, thanks for the explanations.

Comment: Hi! The C DLL function that I want to call from VB is:

void app::Request(const string& input, string& output)
{
 char* outputBuffer = nullptr;
 ExecuteRequest(input.c_str(), &outputBuffer);
 if (outputBuffer)
  output = outputBuffer;
}

But, I can't receive the output correctly...

Thank you everybody.